# Somehow I need to change this part alone <table className="players-team">

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, backbone.js

I have big if else blocks and am trying it to make it simple.

Somehow I need to change this part alone `<table className="players-team">`.

Is it possible to combine all `if else` or I need to put in some variables?

```or-tag-here
 render() {
        let tile;
        console.log("this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsPreviousYear ===" + this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsPreviousYear);
        console.log("this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsCurrentYear === 0" + this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsCurrentYear);

        if (this.state.error) {
            tile = (
                <div className="content-Wrapper action-shadow">
                    <div className="info-section">
                        <p className="negative text-center">Account Information Unavailable</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        } else if(this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsCurrentYear === undefined && this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsPreviousYear === undefined) {
            console.log("this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsCurrentYear === 0 && this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsPreviousYear === 0");
            tile = (
                <div className="data-Wrapper action-shadow">
                    <table className="players-team">                        
                        <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">Current Year ()</th>
                                    <td className="errorRed">Unavailable</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">Prior Year ()</th>
                                    <td className="errorRed">Unavailable</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <ul className="link-team secondary-links">
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" onClick={launchFundsTransfer}>Make a Contribution</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            );
        } else if(this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsCurrentYear === undefined) {
            console.log("this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsCurrentYear");
            tile = (
                <div className="data-Wrapper action-shadow">
                    <table className="players-team">                        
                        <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">Current Year ({ (this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsPreviousYear) + 1 })</th>
                                    <td>{moneyFormat(parseFloat(this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsCurrentYearToDateContributions))}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">Prior Year ({this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsPreviousYear})</th>
                                    <td>{moneyFormat(parseFloat(this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsPreviousYearToDateContributions))}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <ul className="link-team secondary-links">
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" onClick={launchFundsTransfer}>Make a Contribution</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            );
        } else if(this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsPreviousYear === undefined) {
            console.log("this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsPreviousYear === 0");
            tile = (
                <div className="data-Wrapper action-shadow">
                    <table className="players-team">                        
                        <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">Current Year ({(this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsCurrentYear)})</th>
                                    <td>{moneyFormat(parseFloat(this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsCurrentYearToDateContributions))}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">Prior Year ({ (this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsCurrentYear) - 1 })</th>
                                    <td>{moneyFormat(parseFloat(this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsPreviousYearToDateContributions))}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <ul className="link-team secondary-links">
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" onClick={launchFundsTransfer}>Make a Contribution</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            console.log("this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsCurrentYear === value && this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsPreviousYear === value");
            tile = (
                <div className="data-Wrapper action-shadow">
                    <table className="players-team">                        
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">Current Year ({this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsCurrentYear})</th>
                                <td>{moneyFormat(parseFloat(this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsCurrentYearToDateContributions))}</td>
                            </tr> 
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">Prior Year ({this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsPreviousYear})</th>
                                <td>{moneyFormat(parseFloat(this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsPreviousYearToDateContributions))}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <ul className="link-team secondary-links">
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" onClick={launchFundsTransfer}>Make a Contribution</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            );
        }

        return (
            <section className="gray-Wrapper page-top">
                <h2>IRA Contributions</h2>
                <div className="flex-container flex-1">
                    <div className="flex-item half-item">
                        {tile}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: side note: your question doesn't match your title...

Answer (score 0):

- you can maybe
- use a
- switch / case
- structure
- like this..

  ```
  switch(this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsCurrentYear){
      case "1997":
          // do stuff if the value is 1997
          break;
      case "1925":
          // do stuff if the value is 1925
          break;
      default:
          // do stuff if the value is anything else
  }
  ```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Answer (score 0):

When you have a lot of repeated code like that, it is an indication that it should be separated into its own component.

```
render() {
    let tile;
    console.log("this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsPreviousYear ===" + this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsPreviousYear);
    console.log("this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsCurrentYear === 0" + this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsCurrentYear);

    if (this.state.error) {
        tile = (
            <div className="content-Wrapper action-shadow">
                <div className="info-section">
                    <p className="negative text-center">Account Information Unavailable</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    } else {
        <MyTable currentYear={this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsCurrentYear}
                   priorYear={this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsPreviousYear} />
    }
  }
```

Then in your `<MyTable/>` component you can render it like this:

```
 render(){
      <div className="data-Wrapper action-shadow">
          <table className="players-team">
              <tbody>
                      <tr>
                          <th scope="row">**Calculate this value**</th>
                          <td className={calculatedStyle>**Calculate this value**</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <th scope="row">**Calculate this value**</th>
                          <td className={calculatedStyle}>**Calculate this value**</td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody>
          </table>
          <ul className="link-team secondary-links">
              <li><a href="javascript:;" onClick={launchFundsTransfer}>Make a Contribution</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>        
    }
```

Comment: I would remove the <table> HTML into its own separate component.  You can pass the current/previous year to this component as props.  Use logic in the new component to set the className and determine whether to display errors or formatted text.  The <table> structure is only written once this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your state before using values,

```
if(this.state.basketBallDecription.sportsCurrentYear === undefined) {
        //set states here
 }
```

then passing them into your JSX. This way you won't have to repeat JSX.